# Using interpolation in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have two vectors (`latg` and `ch4`): `latg` is a 18225x1 vector, and `ch4` is a 91269x1 vector. I want to size the `latg` vector so that it matches the size of the `ch4` vector by interpolating between the data points.

How do I go about this? Do I use the `interp1` function?

Comment: do you have any breakpoints? Interpolation only works if you have a common axis.

Comment: Could you please give an example with small data set?

Comment: You need to know of a couple of points that correspond to each other between the two vectors... do they start and end at the same point or do they start together and then the smaller vector corresponds to every 5th point on the larger vector etc etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed the interp1 function can be used. I assume you want to linearly interpolate extra datapoints between the limiting values of the smaller array.

```
% Vector to be upscaled
vector1 = latg;
% Number of elements in new vector (vector2, nr of elements same as in ch4)
n_vector2 = length(ch4);
vector2 = interp1( linspace(0,1,length(vector1)), vector1, linspace(0,1,n_vector2));
```

So now vector2 is the same of vector latg except that it contains the same amount of points as vector ch4 obtained by linear interpolation.

Kind regards,

Ernst Jan

Comment: It is important to note that this is making the assumption that the two vectors only align at their starts and ends